# Trying to understand react native with getting local storay with AsyncStorage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I'm not able to console log the saved storage value in a component.

Here's the basic react native page:

```
import React from 'react';
import { AsyncStorage, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

const SavedExercise = (props) => {

  const getStoredExercises = async () => {
    const saved = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@storage_Key');
    return saved;
    // try {
    //   const saved = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@storage_Key');
    //   return saved;
    // } catch (e) {
    //   // saving error
    // }
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>hello</Text>
      {saved}
    </View>
  );

};

const style = StyleSheet.create({

});

export default SavedExercise;
```

I tried a number of various things to try to console log (or output) the saved @storage_key value. This is supposed to an object but saved in a string, and ultimately will have to JSON.parse it. but I'm just trying to get it to log. Unfortunately with no luck.

I keep getting erros like:

`Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {_40, _65, _55, _72}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.`

or

`Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.%s,`

How do I properly get the object thats stored in `@storage_key`?

Answer (score 0):

First of all , `import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';`  has been deprecated , you can check in the docs [rn-deprecated-asyncstorage](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage).

So now you should install [rn-async storage](https://github.com/react-native-community/async-storage) .

After that in your code, where are you setting the  async storage value like `AsyncStorage.setItem('@storage_Key', 'stored value')` and just an quick note yoou can only keep string values in async storage, if you want to keep array or something else you need  to JSON.stringify  it first and when extracting via `const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@storage_Key')` you need to again JSON.parse the value to convert into array or whatever format you want it in.

Try with this. I believe the error is due to you are using deprecated asyncstorage. Try with the one for which ive provided the link.r

Hope it helps. feel free for doubts.

Comment: I'm using expo with my app. So when I tried replacing it with the external module from the react-native-community, I keep getting errors.